# Prioritized result set

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm creating a stored procedure (MySQL) to grab some questions based on some priorities.

1. New questions in matching difficulty (50% of amount)
2. New questions (rest of the questions)
3. Questions that have been answered the minimum amount of times (rest...)

   - in matching difficulty
   - questions

The parameters look like this:

```
(IN _languageCode VARCHAR(5), IN _userId CHAR(36), IN _categoryId CHAR(36), IN _amount int, IN _accuracy DECIMAL(5,2), IN _deviation int)
```

First of all, all questions should match the category and language. This look something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM `QuestionTranslation` AS QT
WHERE QT.LanguageCode = _languageCode AND CASE WHEN _categoryId IS NOT NULL THEN QT.QuestionId IN (SELECT QuestionId FROM `QuestionEntities` WHERE EntityId IN (SELECT EntityId FROM `CategoryTags` WHERE CategoryId = @_categoryId)) ELSE 1 END
ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT _amount;
```

That works fine. This expression can check whether a question is new:

```
QT.QuestionId NOT IN (SELECT QuestionId FROM `Answer` WHERE UserId = _userId GROUP BY QuestionId)
```

Works fine as well. The next expression can check whether a question is in a desired difficulty level:

```
QT.QuestionId NOT IN (SELECT QuestionId FROM (SELECT QuestionId, (1 - SUM(CASE WHEN ChosenAnswer = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / COUNT(*)) * 100 AS Level FROM `Answer` GROUP BY QuestionId HAVING Level < _accuracy - _deviation AND Level > _accuracy + _deviation) AS A)
```

Works great as well. The next query orders the amount of times a question has been answered by the user:

```
SELECT QuestionId FROM `Answer` WHERE UserId = _userId GROUP BY QuestionId ORDER BY COUNT(*)
```

Works fine, but how do I select only the QuestionId's that have been answered the least amount of times?

Next up, is how do I construct the full query with all these subqueries, so it performs the best?

My current approach is to just grab the questions like this:

```
(SELECT Priority 1 LIMIT _amount / 2)
UNION
(SELECT Priority 2 LIMIT _amount)
UNION
(SELECT Priority 3a LIMIT _amount)
UNION
(SELECT Priority 3b LIMIT _amount)
LIMIT 12;
```

which would look something like:

```
(SELECT DISTINCT * FROM `QuestionTranslation` AS QT
    WHERE QT.LanguageCode = _languageCode AND CASE WHEN _categoryId IS NOT NULL THEN QT.QuestionId IN (SELECT QuestionId FROM `QuestionEntities` WHERE EntityId IN (SELECT EntityId FROM `CategoryTags` WHERE CategoryId = _categoryId)) ELSE 1 END
    AND QT.QuestionId NOT IN (SELECT QuestionId FROM `Answer` WHERE UserId = _userId GROUP BY QuestionId)
    AND QT.QuestionId NOT IN (SELECT QuestionId FROM (SELECT QuestionId, (1 - SUM(CASE WHEN ChosenAnswer = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / COUNT(*)) * 100 AS Level FROM `Answer` GROUP BY QuestionId HAVING Level < _accuracy - _deviation AND Level > _accuracy + _deviation) AS A)
    ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT _amount / 2)
UNION
(SELECT DISTINCT * FROM `QuestionTranslation` AS QT
    WHERE QT.LanguageCode = _languageCode AND CASE WHEN _categoryId IS NOT NULL THEN QT.QuestionId IN (SELECT QuestionId FROM `QuestionEntities` WHERE EntityId IN (SELECT EntityId FROM `CategoryTags` WHERE CategoryId = _categoryId)) ELSE 1 END
    AND QT.QuestionId NOT IN (SELECT QuestionId FROM `Answer` WHERE UserId = _userId GROUP BY QuestionId)
    ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT _amount)
UNION
(SELECT DISTINCT * FROM `QuestionTranslation` AS QT
    WHERE QT.LanguageCode = _languageCode AND CASE WHEN _categoryId IS NOT NULL THEN QT.QuestionId IN (SELECT QuestionId FROM `QuestionEntities` WHERE EntityId IN (SELECT EntityId FROM `CategoryTags` WHERE CategoryId = _categoryId)) ELSE 1 END
    AND QT.QuestionId NOT IN (select least answered questions by user .... what to do here?)
    AND QT.QuestionId NOT IN (SELECT QuestionId FROM (SELECT QuestionId, (1 - SUM(CASE WHEN ChosenAnswer = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / COUNT(*)) * 100 AS Level FROM `Answer` GROUP BY QuestionId HAVING Level < _accuracy - _deviation AND Level > _accuracy + _deviation) AS A)
    ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT _amount)
UNION
(SELECT DISTINCT * FROM `QuestionTranslation` AS QT
    WHERE QT.LanguageCode = _languageCode AND CASE WHEN _categoryId IS NOT NULL THEN QT.QuestionId IN (SELECT QuestionId FROM `QuestionEntities` WHERE EntityId IN (SELECT EntityId FROM `CategoryTags` WHERE CategoryId = _categoryId)) ELSE 1 END
    AND QT.QuestionId NOT IN (select least answered questions by user .... what to do here?)
    ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT _amount)
LIMIT _amount;
```

I guess that this not the correct way to achieve this. Any good suggestions on how to approach this for best performance?

Best regards,

Søren

Comment: How often do the priority sets overlap?  In other words, do many records fall into multiple categories or is this quite rare?

Comment: Pretty often. For new users all question will be new, and no matter what I am going to fill the result set up with random new questions. Meaning that only 50% of the result set should consist of questions matching the difficulty level.

Comment: That means, for a new user the three latter subqueries would return identical result sets.